# EC2 AWS - You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I have followed all the steps to launch `EC2` and `RDS` instances. Have installed all the required packages also like `phpmyadmin`, `mysql` etc. Now am getting bellow error when trying `http://my_ip/phpmyadmin`

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

For the solution I have searched a lot and got some solution that I have to change `127.0.0.1` to `my ip address which I got after creating EC2 instance` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`. So when I try to edit this file it says `perrmission denied`. I have used below commands to give permission to `ec2-user`

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo groupadd www

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chown -R root:www /var/www

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www

[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;

[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

And it was working perfectly till the yestarday but I can't understand that suddenly what happened to it. Can anyone please help me?

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip my_ip
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from my_ip
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip my_ip
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from my_ip
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: Were you using `sudo` while editing `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` file?

Comment: I have used `WinSCP` to transfer files from my local machine so am editing `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` file also from there.

Comment: Is that wrong way to edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` file using `WinSCP`?

Comment: Can you ssh into EC2 and run `sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` and make changes.

Comment: Okay! let me try that way.

Comment: `sudo sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/your_ip_address/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` is the command I have used to edit file. but still getting `403 forbidden` in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Restart web server once

Comment: Restarted but still bad luck :(

Comment: Can you share contents of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` on pastebin

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131505/discussion-between-user7-and-deadlock).